# The button click in one row of Jtable changes labels in all table records

Tags: java, swing, listview, jtable

I try to make the list of JPanel with buttons, edittext fields and other Swing components but cant find the examples of making listviews in swing. I tried to do this with jTable that has one column whith JPanel in cells but my label fields changes in all jPanel elements after click of button

Here is the code, that i made from different examples. This class has render and editor methods. I try to change the text of label when button is clicked. But all labels (I want to change only one that is needed) change their text... May be i set onMouseListener not in that place...

```
public class RssFeedCell extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer {
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel text;
    JButton showButton;
    JLabel label;

    RssFeed feed;

    public RssFeedCell() {
        label = new JLabel();
        text = new JLabel();
        showButton = new JButton("View Articles");
        showButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                label.setText("ed");
            }
        });

        panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(showButton);
        panel.add(label);
    }

    private void updateData(RssFeed feed, boolean isSelected, JTable table) {
        this.feed = feed;

        text.setText("" + feed.name + "" + feed.url + "Articles " + feed.articles.length + "");

        if (isSelected) {
            panel.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            panel.setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        RssFeed feed = (RssFeed) value;
        updateData(feed, true, table);
        return panel;
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return null;
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                   boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        RssFeed feed = (RssFeed) value;
        updateData(feed, isSelected, table);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one `label`. You need to incorporate the cell state into the `TableModel` data.

Comment: Yess, sure, all works. I have experience in other languages, but not in java's swing. If somebode need code, i d show it full. Thanks you for answer!